# Delete records based on multiple duplicate columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

**The problem**

I have a table in a SQL Server database that has 5 columns. All columns contain duplicate data (i.e., no one column could be the primary key). Three of the columns MUST be unique when combined (i.e., `TheItem, TheDate`, and `TheValue` would make a composite primary key if declared (it wasn't). None of the 3 columns have null values).

I have identified the duplicates with the following code (below) but am unsure how to modify it to delete the rows which contain duplicates of the 3 columns combined, leaving only one record. I do not care which duplicate(s) get deleted. The `Comments` are all NULL and I don't care which file (`TheFile`) the data came from as long as one of them is identified.

A sample of my original table (> 3 million records):

| TheFile | TheItem | TheDate | TheValue | TheComments |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| FileA | Item1 | 11/2/2014 2:30:00 AM | 35.172 | NULL |
| FileA | Item1 | 11/2/2014 2:30:00 AM | 35.172 | NULL |
| FileB | Item1 | 11/2/2014 2:30:00 AM | 35.172 | NULL |
| FileB | Item1 | 11/2/2014 2:30:00 AM | 35.172 | NULL |
| FileC | Item2 | 12/16/2014 4:30:00 AM | 27.271 | NULL |
| FileD | Item2 | 12/16/2014 4:30:00 AM | 27.271 | NULL |
| FileF | Item3 | 11/17/2014 4:30:00 AM | 47.31 | NULL |
| FileG | Item3 | 11/17/2014 4:30:00 AM | 47.31 | NULL |
| FileH | Item4 | 7/15/2014 4:30:00 AM | 56.684 | NULL |
| FileH | Item4 | 7/15/2014 4:30:00 AM | 56.684 | NULL |

The SQL code:

```
SELECT 
    TheItem, TheDate, TheValue, Count(*) AS TheCount
FROM
    TheTable
GROUP BY 
    TheItem, TheDate, TheValue
HAVING 
    COUNT(*) > 1
ORDER BY 
    TheCount DESC
```

The results (~400,000 records):

| TheItem | TheDate | TheValue | TheCount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Item1 | 11/2/2014 2:30:00 AM | 35.172 | 4 |
| Item2 | 12/16/2014 4:30:00 AM | 27.271 | 2 |
| Item3 | 11/17/2014 4:30:00 AM | 47.31 | 2 |
| Item4 | 7/15/2014 4:30:00 AM | 56.684 | 2 |

What code would be best for querying > 3M records and then deleting hundreds of thousands of duplicates? I am using SSMS v19.1.

Thank you.

Comment: The version of SSMS is irrelevant as its just a client UI, please provide `select @@version`

Comment: When you say "best" what criteria counts as best? Is your delete (please show us) too slow? Or what?